# OpenCV (python) fundamental and essential matrix do not agree

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I try to calibrate a stereo camera with OpenCV (python interface). I first calibrated the two cameras separately with calibrateCamera2 and then fed the parameters to stereoCalibrate

```
cv.StereoCalibrate(object_points, image_points_left, image_points_right, \
               point_counts, intrinsic_left, distortion_left,\
               intrinsic_right, distortion_right, \
               (IMGRES_X,IMGRES_Y), R, T, E, F, \
               term_crit=(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-8),\
               flags=cv.CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
```

I check the result with the epipolar constraint (as described in the OpenCV book) and get an *average* error of around 0.0039.

In principle I should be able to relate the fundamental and the essential matrix with my camera matrices. So what I do is:

```
Mr = asarray(intrinsic_right,dtype=float64)
Ml = asarray(intrinsic_left,dtype=float64)
E = asarray(E)
F = asarray(F)
F2 = dot(dot(inv(Mr).T,E),inv(Ml))
```

However, the resulting matrix F2 does not at all resemble F. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong? Help is much appreciated.

**Edit:** dot and inv are from numpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The E and F matrices returned by StereoCalibrate() are correct. F is defined up to scale, hence if you're going to compare the returned F and with the F matrix computed from E you need to normalize them to make sure both are at the same scale. So when you look at them they seem the same. StereoCalibrate() normalizes the returned F, thus you need to normalize the computed F2 as you have noted in one of your comments. I hope that makes it more clear why you need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to The [Fundamental Matix Song](http://danielwedge.com/fmatrix/)...

But seriously, perhaps it's something 'normalising" in  the dot-products? The standard numpy `dot` function does seem to correctly act to split matrices into individual row and column vectors for multiplication.

For example, if I do:

```
A = mat(random.rand(3,3))
B = mat(random.rand(3,3))
dot(A,B) == A*B
```

Instead, I wonder if it helps to perform the straight-forward matrix multiplication as:

```
F2 = np.linalg.inv(Mr.T) * E * np.linalg.inv(Ml)
```

(N.B. I'm working with numpy matrices here)

Comment: I am using numpy's dot function, because I work with numpy arrays. I actually just found out that scaling F2 via F2 /= F2[2,2] yields the correct results. However, that still confuses me, because according to the API, my computations from above should be correct. And honestly, I don't know how the song adds to that. I know what a fundamental matrix is, I just want to know why OpenCV gets it wrong.

Comment: Ah, sounds like some of the matrices have/not been normalised. I've never noticed that with OpenCV before. I might have a look at the underlying source code. The song was only a light-hearted reference. Apologies for confusing you further!

Comment: Ah, ok. Does it matter that the matrix is not normalized? I mean, will I get wrong results when using it further? Concerning the song, apologies from my side for reacting a bit rough. I am sure you meant it light-hearted. I am just annoyed that functions actually compute different things than stated in the API.

Comment: No worries. It is annoying when things differ from the API. I'm going to have a look at this myself when a spare moment. BTW - my stupid error for not casting the above examples to `mat()` matrices. It does then equal the same thing. Editing it above.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed in your favor that you converted everything to matrices :).

Comment: One quick final though... I seem to remember the essential matrix is for use with normalised image coordinates, whereas the fundamental matrix is metric (as applied by the calibration matrices). I wonder where your original calibration points normalised?

Comment: No, they were not. I think what you mean is that if the coordinates are normalized, then the fundamental matrix and the essential matrix coincide (since the camera matrix becomes the identity).

Comment: Perhaps my answer makes it more clear why you need to normalize F2.